# Visual Studio 2015 Community не попадает в точку дебага

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Добрый день. Столкнулся с следующей проблемой.Солюшн состоит из 6 проектов (сайт WEB API + Angular), в одном из них я розставил точки дебага. При запуске проекта я в них не попадаю, хотя должен. Если вручную сделать attach to process, я попаду в точку , но нельзя же постоянно атачить к процессу. подскажите решение проблемы. Спасибо

Comment: Проверьте, что запускаете в режиме Debug - раз. Проверьте что в Advanced Build Settings для проекта - опция Debug Info не выставлена в none

Comment: 1. Стоит ли режим debug (там окошко debug/resease). 2. Есть ли метка на точке, студия показывает дополнительно на красной метке заметку если тока не верно по версии microsoft поставлена (за пределами исполнимого кода, или другие причины что нельзя поставить точку)

Comment: @A K @nick_n_a 1)Запускаю в режиме Debug. 2)Проверил Advanced Build Settings->Debug Info установлено в full.3)Режим стоит Debug 4)Точку ставить там можно, меток нет..

Comment: @A K @nick_n_a будто на iis развернуты не совсем те сорс файлы с которыми я работаю, а дубликатов проекта на компе нет..

Comment: Попробуйте buid->batch build->select all->rebuild
Сталкивался с подобным, когда решение состоит из нескольких проектов-библиотек. При чем при полном ребилде в окне Error list ошибки появляются и тут же исчезают - тогда каждую либу отдельно ребилд, пока ошибки конкретной либы не вылезут. Что за баг в VS - не знаю, сам не разобрался

Comment: @kvvk если глянуть список процессов, то там будет 3 процесса типа iis .автоматически он конектится к одному из них, а что бы попасть в дебаг ему нужно приатачиться к 3 процессам сразу..не подскажите как решить это?

Comment: @andrey_KU внутрь не лазил, сорри

Comment: @andrey_KU и почему три процесса? какого типа проект? попробовал тестовый MVC 5 на VS2015 Community - в процессах только один iisexpress

Comment: @kvvk в солюшине есть Api.Web проект, Client.Web, Admin.Web и получается что для каждого система открывает свой процесс..если запустить проект то в трэе мы откроем iis и увидим 3 запущеных сайта.если потушить один из них и при этом посмотреть в список запущенных процессов (Ctrl+Alt+Del) мы увидим как 1 процесс пропал

Comment: @andrey_KU 1. попробуйте стартовым сделать исследуемый проект; 2. возможно, исследуемый модуль не подгружается 3.если не получается так (у меня больше идей нет) попробуйте вести лог нужной инфы